# "Recipients Emailed" Quota Reached When Emailing Same Address Multiple Times

Tags: email, google-app-engine, go, quota

I have written an application on Google App Engine that sends emails to a single address. The application reached it's "Recipients Emailed" quota limit during testing. Should the same email address be counted more than once for the "Recipients Emailed" quota?

This is the code sending the emails.

```
import  "google.golang.org/appengine/mail"
```

-

```
msg := &mail.Message{
    Sender:   "Order <order@xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspotmail.com>",
    To:       []string{"Ben <xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>"},
    Subject:  "Order Received",
    HTMLBody: htmlBody,
}
if err := mail.Send(ctx, msg); err != nil {
    log.Errorf(ctx, "Couldn't send email: %v", err)
}
```

My Quota Usage
[image: My Quota Usage]

[Google's API Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Mail)
[image: Google's API Quotas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is how it's actually counted. The resource naming used is misleading.

Note that the measurement units in the table are actually `messages` and `mails` not recipients/admins.